# Moving a Web app to Google App Engine. is it right?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am building a Web App using Codeigniter and MySQL and completed most of the part.

But then i encounter with Google App Engine that offer great features like one dont have to worry about scalability and infrastructure.

Now i was thinking of Hosting it on Google app Engine rather than on a Dedicated Server.

Before asking a question i want to make a few points.

1. It will consume time as i have to rewrite the code in Django(Yes i can use quercus but i think there will be some performance issue).
2. I read some other answers saying that "GAE better if your site is 'Huge'". this app could be but for now its not "HUGE".
3. i am developing the App by my own so it could be better since i dont have to worry about Scaling and all... i can concentrate more on Logic Part.
4. Final solution would be wait for app's eligibility criteria("Huge") and then Port it in to  App engine.

So is it better idea to build a Web App on GAE with Datastore or should i use a Traditional Server?

Comment: How much time will you spent with the setup of your server and the webserver maintenance. My experience : almost zero and no downtime and if your app has errors, you can configure a dayly report. Have a look at : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfG3Bf8bygk

Comment: @voscausa thanks for video link...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If scalability and infrastructure made you consider Google appengine but your project has already begun development with PHP+MySQL, maybe you should take a look over other IaaS alternatives to appengine such as Appfog and Dotcloud (these two provide a free tier just like appengine) among others, as they provide a wider range of runtime environments (php included) and assorted data base backends such as MySQL. That way you won't have to port any code.

http://www.appfog.com
http://www.dotcloud.com